# How do I use the Antlr generated junit file made by translating a gunit file

Tags: junit, antlr, antlr3, gunit

I am trying to make unit tests for multiple return values in Antlr. I have regular unit tests working using gunit. However, I am not too sure what to do with the junit Testgrammar.java file that is generated as per the instructions at http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/gUnit+-+Grammar+Unit+Testing

I've tried running:

java -cp "./antlr.jar" Testgrammar.java

but I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Testgrammar/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be compiled linking to the build output of the grammar files and then run with:

java org/junit/runner/JUnitCore Testgrammar

Answer (score 1):

You run it like any other Java app: with the classname, not the file name.

```
java -cp "./antlr.jar" Testgrammar
```

Comment: it has something to do with running it with junit. I am just not that familiar with setting it up from the command line.

Comment: Not sure about running with JUnit, just spotted the error in your command line call there